# C pass value to matlab and get result from it

Tags: c, matlab

I'm working with C program, and have a simple C code to generate data like follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

double x[100];
int i;
srand(3);
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    x[i] = (double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

I want to pass this array into matlab, and do the following calculate:

```
y = transpose(x)
Mdl = arima(1,0,0)
[EstMdl,EstParamCov,logL,info] = estimate(Mdl,y)
a = EstMdl.AR
b = EstMdl.Variance
```

How can I pass array x to matlab and get a and b back from matlab using C language?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-programs-1.html

Comment: Is there any function can run .m file with command line in C?